# Encontrar libro de acuerdo al autor ingresado a partir de una clase biblioteca

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

estoy tratando de encontrar un libro de acuerdo al autor ingresado a partir de una clase biblioteca. Tengo parte del codigo avanzado pero no se como comparar lo que ingresa el usuario con los atributos de la clase biblioteca. Podrian indicarme como puedo hacer?

```
class biblioteca{
  constructor(libro,autor){
    this.libro = libro;
    this.autor = autor;
  }
}
var dato = prompt("Introduce autor")
const autor1 = new biblioteca("CesarVallejo","LosHeraldosNegros");
const autor2 = new biblioteca("PauloCoelho","ElAlquimista");
const autor3 = new biblioteca("RicardoPalma","TradicionesPeruanas");
/*

Codigo faltante

*/
```

Comment: Creo que el enfoque no es correcto, la clase biblioteca debería ir almacenando los libros en un arreglo, de preferencia, con otra clase para crear cada libro.

Comment: Comentario aparte, trata de usar convenciones estándar al momento de nombrar tus Clases. La convención es que uses letra mayúscula al inicio del nombre de la Clase: `Biblioteca`. Si fuese un nombre compuesto puedes usar `UpperCamelCase` ([`PascalCase`](http://wiki.c2.com/?CapitalizationRules)). Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes utilizar el método Find, o el Método Filter de un array, pero primero deberías crear el array de objetos de la cl

```js
class Biblioteca{
  constructor(autor,libro){
    this.libro = libro;
    this.autor = autor;
  }
}
let conjuntoLibros = []

var dato = prompt("Introduce autor")
conjuntoLibros.push(new Biblioteca("CesarVallejo","LosHeraldosNegros"));
conjuntoLibros.push(new Biblioteca("CesarVallejo","LosHeraldosNegros2"));
conjuntoLibros.push(new Biblioteca("CesarVallejo","LosHeraldosNegros3"));
conjuntoLibros.push(new Biblioteca("PauloCoelho","ElAlquimista"));
conjuntoLibros.push(new Biblioteca("RicardoPalma","TradicionesPeruanas"));

console.log(conjuntoLibros)

//Con Find, encontrar solo el primer resultado
console.log(conjuntoLibros.find(libro => libro.autor === dato))

//Con Filter, devuelve todos los que cumplan
console.log(conjuntoLibros.filter(libro => libro.autor === dato))
```

Como comenta Triby:

```js
class Biblioteca{
  constructor(){
    this.libros = []
  }
  
  addLibro(autor,libro){
    this.libros.push({autor:autor,titulo:libro})
  }
  
  getLibrosByAutor(autor){
    return this.libros.filter(libro => libro.autor === autor)
  }
  
  getLibroByTitulo(titulo){
    return this.libros.find(libro => libro.titulo === titulo)
  }
  
}
let biblioteca = new Biblioteca()


biblioteca.addLibro("CesarVallejo","LosHeraldosNegros");
biblioteca.addLibro("CesarVallejo","LosHeraldosNegros2");
biblioteca.addLibro("CesarVallejo","LosHeraldosNegros3");
biblioteca.addLibro("PauloCoelho","ElAlquimista");
biblioteca.addLibro("RicardoPalma","TradicionesPeruanas");


var autor_buscado = prompt("Introduce autor")
var titulo_buscado = prompt("Introduce Titulo")



console.log(biblioteca.getLibrosByAutor(autor_buscado))

console.log(biblioteca.getLibroByTitulo(titulo_buscado))
```

Comment: Si bien, con esta respuesta se puede buscar, creo que una aproximación mejor encaminada sería que el arreglo sea parte de la clase, inicializado en el constructor, creando los métodos necesarios para agregar y buscar libros.

Comment: Si claramente, pero para eso habría que rediseñar toda la clase, para que admita almacenar un arreglo en si misma, y el constructor ya no seria para los libros.

Comment: ¡Exactamente! Porque el funcionamiento (desde la pregunta) no cumple con la premisa de _"buscar a partir de una clase"_, sino que está buscando a partir de un arreglo con elementos generados por una clase, que son dos cosas totalmente diferentes.

Comment: ¡Mucho mejor ahora! +1